# Loading storage files from another server

Tags: laravel, file-storage

I've put the database and files on separate servers (because I've set up 3 servers for our web application and use the load balancer for them) and I use SFTP for filestorage driver.

Because I've used the SFTP driver for Laravel file storage, the SSH connection to the destination server will increase and the SSH port will be block and the files cannot load from the storage server.

What should I do? is there any other solution to load files from another server?

Comment: Probably not that helpful, but I'd strongly recommend using DigitalOcean Spaces or S3 to store (and serve) files (if possible).

Comment: Laravel uses Flysystem which seems to have [an SFTP adapter](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/adapter/sftp/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a cloud storage for this usecase, in which one can set the CORS settings. You could for instance use [aws s3](https://aws.amazon.com/de/s3/) for this or use [digital ocean spaces](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/spaces/) which has a similiar api to s3.

You basically post your to that cloud server and save the url to your database.
Of course you need to set of the [cors](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) settings, to basically say that server x can access specific files on the cloud storage.